# Efficient Datastructure for tags?

Tags: c#, data-structures, bitarray

Imagine you wanted to serialize and deserialize stackoverflow posts including their tags as space efficiently as possible (in binary), but also for performance when doing tag  lookups. Is there a good datastructure for that kind of scenario?

Stackoverflow has about 28532 different tags, you could create a table with all tags and assign them an integer, Furthermore you could sort them by frequency so that the most common tags have the lowest numbers. Still storing them simply like a string in the format "1 32 45" seems a bit inefficent borth from a searching and storing perspective

Another idea would be to save tags as a variable bitarray which is attractive from a lookup and serializing perspective. Since the most common tags are first you potentially could fit tags into a small amount of memory.

The problem would be of course that uncommon tags would yield huge bitarrays. Is there any standard for "compressing"  bitarrays for large spans of 0's? Or should one use some other structure completely?

**EDIT**

I'm not looking for a DB solution or a solution where I need to keep entire tables in memory, but a structure for filtering individual items

Answer (score 3):

Not to undermine your question but 28k records is really not all that many. Are you perhaps optimizing prematurely? 
I would first stick to using 'regular' indices on a DB table. The harshing heuristics they use are typically very efficient and not trivial to beat (or if you can is it really worth the effort in time and are the gains large enough?).

Also depending on where you actually do the tag query, is the user really noticing the 200ms time gain you optimized for?

First measure then optimize :-)

EDIT

Without a DB I would probably have a master table holding all tags together with an ID (if possible hold it in memory). Keep a regular sorted list of IDs together with each post.

Not sure how much storage based on commonality would help. A sorted list in which you can do a regular binary search may prove fast enough; measure :-)

Here you would need to iterate all posts for every tag query though.

If this ends up being to slow you could resort to storing a pocket of post identifiers for each tag. This data structure may become somewhat large though and may require a file to seek and read against.

For a smaller table you could resort to build one based on a hashed value (with duplicates). This way you could use it to quickly get down to a smaller candidate list of posts that need further checking to see if they match or not.

Comment: there's no DB in this scenario, and the question is about the structure, assume the scenario is warranted ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need second table with 2 fields: tag_id question_id

That's it. Then you create indexes on tag_id, question_id and question_id, tag_id - that would be covering index so all your queries would be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you abstracted your question too much; you didn't say very much about how you want to *access* the datastructure, which is very important.

That being said, I suggest to count the number of occurances for each tag and then use [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) to come up with the shortest encoding which can be used for the tags. This is not entirely perfect, but I'd stick with it until you've demonstrate that it's inappropriate. You can then associate the codes with each question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to efficiently lookup questions within a specific tag, you will need some kind of index. Maybe, all Tag objects could have an array of references (references, pointers, nummeric-id, etc) to all the questions that are tagged with this particular tag. This way you simply need to find the tag object and you have an array pointing to all the questions of that tag.