# Algorithms and data structures for 'tag' or key word based query on large data set?

Tags: database, algorithm, search, storage

I am trying to implement a storage system to support tagging on data. A very simple application of this system is like questions on Stackoverflow, which are tagged with multiple tags. And a query may consist of multiple tags. This also looks like search on Google with multiple key words.

The data set maintained by this system will be very large, like several or tens of terabytes with billions of entries.

So what data structures and algorithms should I use in this system for maintaining and query data? And the data may be stored across a cluster of machines.

Are there any guide or papers to describe such problem and solutions?

Comment: Why not to use some document oriented database, like MongoDB or CouchDB?

Comment: @Lazin because I am implementing it.

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6405/data-structure-that-allow-efficient-tag-based-lookups

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254230/efficient-datastructure-for-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read the two books below:

1. **Collective Intelligence in Action**

   Satnam Alag (ISBN: 1933988312)
   http://www.manning.com/alag/

   "Capter 3. Extracting intelligence from tags" covers:

   - Three forms of tagging and the use of tags
   - A working example of how intelligence is extracted from tags
   - Database architecture for tagging
   - Developing tag clouds
2. **Programming Collective Intelligence**

   Toby Segaran (ISBN: 978-0-596-52932-1)
   http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do

   "Chapter 4. Searching and Ranking" covers:

   - Basic concepts of algorithms for search engine index
   - Design of a click-tracking neural network

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is very difficult, but there is a plenty of related papers and books. [Amazon Dynamo paper](http://www.read.seas.harvard.edu/~kohler/class/cs239-w08/decandia07dynamo.pdf), [yahoo PNUTS](http://www.mpi-sws.org/~druschel/courses/ds/papers/cooper-pnuts.pdf) and this [hadoop paper](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.18.0/hdfs_design.pdf) is a good examples. 
So, at first, you must decide how your data will be distributed across cluster. Data must be evenly distributed across network, without hot spots. Consistent hashing will be a good solution for this problem. Also, data must be redundant, any entry need to be stored in several places to tolerate faults of individual nodes.

Next, you must decide how writes will occur in your system. Every write must be replicated across nodes that contains updated data entry. You might want to read about CAP theorem, and eventual consistency concept(wikipedia have a good article about both). Also, there is a consistency - latency tradeoff. You can use different mechanisms for writes replication: some kind of gossip protocol or [state machine replication](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/implementation.pdf).

I don't know what kind of tagging do you mean, is this tags manually assigned to entries or learned from data. Anyway, this is a field of information retrieval(IR). You might use some kind of inverted index to effectively search entries by tags or keywords. Also, you must use some query result ranking algorithm.